# PHP unexpected character encoding

Tags: php, string, encoding

I have a PHP script that fetches an ICS file, makes some changes to it, and rewrites it for download using `Content-Type: application/ics` and `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.ics"`. The script works fine. However, some characters like `'` get converted to `&#039;`, but not all of them, only those in lines that I have modified.

When I `var_dump` the string that is being written as payload, the browser displays all characters fine.

Any idea ?

EDIT: I use an ICS parser from [here](https://github.com/johngrogg/ics-parser). The problem comes from it but after looking through the code I can't find where it could replace some characters by `htmlentities`.

Comment: Of course the browser will decode HTML entities and display them as characters. How they get to be HTML entities in the first place we cannot tell you with the information given.

Comment: Indeed you are right, I just `echo htmlentities($payload)` and the characters are in fact already not properly encoded. Now I just have to find where the change occurs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to converts `&#[0-9]+` entities to `UTF-8`, you can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) for that, i.e.:

```
$string = "stack user&#039;s";
echo preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", function($m) { return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); }, $string); 
//stack user's
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Rt5dMg)

Comment: Fixed, works like a charm. I think the characters were converted by the [ICS parser I use](https://github.com/johngrogg/ics-parser). I look through their code but couldn't find where they replace some characters to `htmlentities`.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to decode html characters while you are modifying the file:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php